# Class not found in Module.php in zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

New issue is raised while creating crud operation, I have province module which is similar to Album module. Here I want to add new province as will as delete and update province. I copied code from album, everything is ok, but it shows an error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Admin\Provinces' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\new_project\module\Admin\Module.php:61 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Admin\Module->Admin{closure}  (Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'provincestableg...', 'ProvincesTableG...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\new_project\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(939): call_user_func(Object(Closure), Object(Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager), 'provincestableg...', 'ProvincesTableG...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\new_project\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(1099): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createServiceViaCallback(Object(Closure), 'provincestableg...', 'ProvincesTableG...') #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\new_project\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(638): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->createFromFactory('provincestableg...', 'ProvincesTableG...') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\new_project\vendor\zendframework\zend-servicemanager\src\ServiceManager.php(598): Zend\ServiceMana in C:\xampp\htdocs\new_project\module\Admin\Module.php on line 61

Module.php:

```
<?php 

namespace Admin;

use Admin\Model\Profile;
use Admin\Model\ProfileTable;
use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{

public function getConfig()
{
    return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
}

public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array( 
            'Admin\Model\ProfileTable' =>  function($sm) {
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('ProfileTableGateway');
                $table = new ProfileTable($tableGateway);
                return $table;
            }, 

            'ProfileTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Profile());
                return new TableGateway('user', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);         
            },  
'Admin\Model\ProvincesTable' =>  function($sm) {
                $tableGateway = $sm->get('ProvincesTableGateway');
                $table = new ProvincesTable($tableGateway);
                return $table;
            },
            'ProvincesTableGateway' => function ($sm) {
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Provinces());
                return new TableGateway('provinces', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
            },      
        ),
    );
}

public function getAutoloaderConfig()
{
    return array(
        'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
            'namespaces' => array(
                __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
            ),
        ),
    );
}
}
```

ProvincesController.php:

```
<?php

namespace Admin\Controller;

 use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
 use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

 use Admin\Model\Provinces;           
 use Admin\Form\ProvincesForm;

 class ProvincesController extends AbstractActionController
 {

protected $provincesTable;    
public function getAuthService()
{
    $this->authservice = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('AuthService'); 
    return $this->authservice;  
}

 public function indexAction()
 {   
    $this->layout("layout/layout_admin");   

    // below condition is new and for back browser validation
    if (!$this->getServiceLocator()
            ->get('AuthService')->hasIdentity()) {
        return $this->plugin(redirect)->toRoute('login', array('action' => 'index'));
    } 

     return new ViewModel(array(
     'pk_provinces' => $this->getProvincesTable()->fetchAll(),
     ));

 }

 public function addAction()
 {   
     $form = new ProvincesForm();
     $form->get('submit')->setValue('Add');

     $request = $this->getRequest();
     if ($request->isPost()) {
         $provinces = new Provinces();
         $form->setInputFilter($provinces->getInputFilter());
         $form->setData($request->getPost());

         if ($form->isValid()) {
             $provinces->exchangeArray($form->getData());
             $this->getProvincesTable()->saveProvinces($provinces);

             // Redirect to list of albums
             return $this->redirect()->toRoute('provinces');
         }
     }
     return array('form' => $form);  
 }

 public function editAction()
 {   
     $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
     if (!$id) {
         return $this->redirect()->toRoute('provinces', array(
             'action' => 'add'
         ));
     }

     // Get the Album with the specified id.  An exception is thrown
     // if it cannot be found, in which case go to the index page.
     try {
         $provinces = $this->getProvincesTable()->getProvinces($id);
     }
     catch (\Exception $ex) {
         return $this->redirect()->toRoute('provinces', array(
             'action' => 'index'
         ));
     }

     $form  = new ProvincesForm();
     $form->bind($provinces);
     $form->get('submit')->setAttribute('value', 'Edit');

     $request = $this->getRequest();
     if ($request->isPost()) {
         $form->setInputFilter($provinces->getInputFilter());
         $form->setData($request->getPost());

         if ($form->isValid()) {
             $this->getProvincesTable()->saveProvinces($provinces);

             // Redirect to list of albums
             return $this->redirect()->toRoute('provinces');
         }
     }

     return array(
         'id' => $id,
         'form' => $form,
     );  
 }

 public function deleteAction()
 {   
     $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
     if (!$id) {
         return $this->redirect()->toRoute('provinces');
     }

     $request = $this->getRequest();
     if ($request->isPost()) {
         $del = $request->getPost('del', 'No');

         if ($del == 'Yes') {
             $id = (int) $request->getPost('id');
             $this->getProvincesTable()->deleteProvinces($id);
         }

         // Redirect to list of albums
         return $this->redirect()->toRoute('provinces');
     }

     return array(
         'id'    => $id,
         'provinces' => $this->getProvincesTable()->getProvinces($id)
     );  
 } 

 public function getProvincesTable()
 {
     if (!$this->provincesTable) {
         $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
         $this->provincesTable = $sm->get('Admin\Model\ProvincesTable');
     }
     return $this->provincesTable;
 }
}
```

ProvincesForm.php:

```
<?php

namespace Admin\Form;    
use Zend\Form\Form;

 class ProvincesForm extends Form
 {
     public function __construct($name = null)
     {
         // we want to ignore the name passed
         parent::__construct('provinces');

     $this->add(array(
         'name' => 'id',
         'type' => 'Hidden',
     ));
     $this->add(array(
         'name' => 'p_name',
         'type' => 'Text',
         'options' => array(
             'label' => 'Province',
         ),
     )); 
     $this->add(array(
         'name' => 'submit',
         'type' => 'Submit',
         'attributes' => array(
             'value' => 'Go',
             'id' => 'submitbutton',
         ),
     ));
 }
 }
```

Model/Provinces.php:

```
<?php

 namespace Admin\Model;

 use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;
 use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterAwareInterface;
 use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;

 class Provinces implements InputFilterAwareInterface
 {
     public $id;
     public $p_name;

 protected $inputFilter;

 public function exchangeArray($data)
 {
     $this->id     = (!empty($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
     $this->p_name = (!empty($data['p_name'])) ? $data['p_name'] : null; 
 }

 public function getArrayCopy()
 {
     return get_object_vars($this);
 }

 public function setInputFilter(InputFilterInterface $inputFilter)
 {
     throw new \Exception("Not used");
 }

 public function getInputFilter()
 {
     if (!$this->inputFilter) {
         $inputFilter = new InputFilter();

         $inputFilter->add(array(
             'name'     => 'id',
             'required' => true,
             'filters'  => array(
                 array('name' => 'Int'),
             ),
         ));

         $inputFilter->add(array(
             'name'     => 'p_name',
             'required' => true,
             'filters'  => array(
                 array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                 array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
             ),
             'validators' => array(
                 array(
                     'name'    => 'StringLength',
                     'options' => array(
                         'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                         'min'      => 1,
                         'max'      => 100,
                     ),
                 ),
             ),
         ));

         $this->inputFilter = $inputFilter;
     }
     return $this->inputFilter;
 }
 }
```

Model/ProvincesTable.php:

```
<?php

namespace Admin\Model;    
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

 class ProvincesTable
 {
 protected $tableGateway;

 public function __construct(TableGateway $tableGateway)
 {
     $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
 }

 public function fetchAll()
 {
     $resultSet = $this->tableGateway->select();
     return $resultSet;
 }

 public function getProvinces($id)
 {
     $id  = (int) $id;
     $rowset = $this->tableGateway->select(array('id' => $id));
     $row = $rowset->current();
     if (!$row) {
         throw new \Exception("Could not find row $id");
     }
     return $row;
 }

 public function saveProvinces(Provinces $provinces)
 {
     $data = array(
         'p_name' => $provinces->p_name, 
     );

     $id = (int) $provinces->id;
     if ($id == 0) {
         $this->tableGateway->insert($data);
     } else {
         if ($this->getProvinces($id)) {
             $this->tableGateway->update($data, array('id' => $id));
         } else {
             throw new \Exception('Province id does not exist');
         }
     }
 }

 public function deleteProvinces($id)
 {
     $this->tableGateway->delete(array('id' => (int) $id));
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `use Admin\Model\Province` in your Module.php

Comment: Thank you sir, Thanks alot.